# pixel clock generation for xga 65MHZ

Tags: fpga

Good morning,
I am designing a xga timing generator in verilog but my problem is i am not sure how to create a pixel clock using 65 MHZ for xga specification.
Does anyone have any idea?. Thank you very  much in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to generate a 65 MHz clock in a testbench? If yes, then please edit your question accordingly. You will find an **edit** link below your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what family of FPGA you're using, but they all have some sort of PLL-based clock management resources that are very flexible, and can synthesize fairly arbitrary clocks from a given reference frequency.

The vendor's FPGA tools will include a piece of software that configures the clock generator for you, and the output will include a simulatable model of it. Any external reference clocks will be generated by simple behavioral models in your testbench.

Comment: is it possible to write a pixel clock generator when the code will be simulated in vcs simulator?. or the pixel clock is only needed when the code will be loaded to an fpga board?